# Moving custom tabs/subtabs around on forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, netsuite

I am having an issue trying to insert a custom tab to a specific slot. I can add the tab and populate the tab with a sublist just fine. But the tab goes to the end of all the other tabs. I want to move it to be the second tab in the row. I found insertTab(tab, nexttab) but I keep getting an error. I am not creating a new form, I am just doing a beforeload action on the sales order form. So I do not know if this is my issue or I am just using it wrong. My code is simple but here is how I am adding the tab and sublist.

```
    var newTab = form.addTab('custpage_newpage', 'Name of Tab');
    var newSublist = form.addSubList('custpage_newsublist', 'list','My name', 'custpage_newpage')
    newSubList.addField('customrecord','text','My Field');
```

Can I insert a tab with my above code or do I need to change something?

Comment: I forgot to put the error in that description. Here is the error I receive:
Can't find method .nlobjForm.insertTab(string,string)

Comment: I resolved this by using the follwing code: form.insertTab(newTab, 's_comm');

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below where `nexttab` is the id of the tab you want insert your new tab.
If it is a custom tab, it should start with `custom`

```
var newTab = form.addTab('custpage_newpage', 'Name of Tab');
var newSublist = form.addSubList('custpage_newsublist', 'list','My name','custpage_newpage')
newSubList.addField('customrecord','text','My Field');
form.insertTab(newTab , nexttab)
```